# Using OR in WHERE produces unexpected results

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In a query today I wanted to select rows that had a particular company name in either of two columns from two different tables. I did it like

```
WHERE (N.COMPANY LIKE '%ACME%' OR C.COMPANY LIKE '%ACME%')
```

First, it took 20 minutes to run, which was odd because if I only filtered on one of the columns it took about 10 seconds. Second, when it finished, values for some columns in some rows were NULL when I know for a fact there are values in the database for those columns in those records.  So what is going on here? Why can't SQL do the OR on two columns from two tables?

(I worked around it with a UNION - I ran it for `C.COMPANY LIKE '%ACME%'` and UNIONED it with a `SELECT... WHERE N.COMPANY LIKE '%ACME%'`)

Comment: What do you mean "values for some rows were NULL"? Obviously you're doing a join that you're not showing us, and you're doing it wrong!

Comment: We'll need the full query (or maybe a scaled down version, reproducing your problem), some sample input and output and actual output.

Comment: I cleaned up the text to clarify what I meant. The entire query is large and has about 5 joins. It works fine without the compound OR in the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to mix up the `JOIN` and the `WHERE` keyword in one single query, because `WHERE` is an `INNER JOIN` behind the scenes. From my experience this often results in uncontrolled joins which one don't want.

Try to place your `LIKE`'s after the join of the corresponding tables directly like this:

```
...
JOIN N ON <Your existing relationship> AND N.COMPANY LIKE '%ACME%'
...
JOIN C ON <Your existing relationship> AND C.COMPANY LIKE '%ACME%'
...
```